# How to disable even checking of updates in Windows 8? An svchost process is connected to Microsoft Update server, hogging up resources all the time

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I usually keep the updated on "Notify only" setting but still Windows is keeping an `svchost.exe` process running in the background all the time, which very often connects to a Microsoft Update server ([134.170.165.249](http://134.170.165.249)) which spikes CPU to maximum.

It happens especially when I come back from Standby, significantly affecting the ability to resume the work instantly.

Is there a way to completely turn off the Update, so that doesn't even do checks? I only do manual updates so it's useless for me to know that updates are available anyways.

Comment: I think it is better to see what in detail causes the CPU usage. Provide a xperf trace of the CPU usage: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option **Do Not Check At All** to disable the update check. (Never check for updates (not recommended) from the drop-down box under Important updates to completely disable automatic downloads, installations, and even checks for updates.)

Steps below:

1.) Open Windows Update by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button. In the search box, type Update, and then, in the list of results, click Windows Update.

2.) In the left pane, click Change settings.
This will open a window with a Choose your Windows Update settings heading.

3.) Under Important updates, choose the option that you want - **Do Not Check At All**